# Java Regex checking valid chars for a maze

Tags: java, regex

This check needs to ensure that all lines from the file begin with a wall and have at most one entrance, at most, one exit, and end with a wall. I split up the conditions so I can test them. It fails for cs = "WWWW", "WXW", "WWWWWWWWRWWWWWW"

```
/** 
 * Check to ensure all lines are only composed of walls, 
 * entrance, exit, and space
 */
protected boolean invalidMazeCharacters(CharSequence cs) {

    p = Pattern.compile("^W+(R??W*|X??|W*|\\s*W*)W+$");
    m = p.matcher(cs);
    if (!m.matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: **What are you checking for?**

Comment: I am checking for each line or char sequence to begin with 'W', end with 'W' and have at most one 'R' or at most one 'X' between the walls.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^W+(R?W*X?|X?W*R?)W+$
```

It's not the most efficient, but you can work on improving it. :)  Also, I'm not sure what your rules for spaces are....

*ADDENDUM*

```
^W[W\s]*(?:R?[W\s]*X?|X?[W\s]*R?)[W\s]*W$
```

See http://regexr.com?309c6

Don't forget, if you are using a Java string, to double up the backslashes.

Also, the fact that spaces can appear almost anywhere leads me to suspect that a non-regex-based function would be just fine, too.  You can always iterate through the sequence, counting Rs and Xs, ignoring spaces, making sure the first and last characters are Ws, and returning `false` as soon as you see a bad character or extra R or W.

Comment: ok, thanks will try that.  The rules for spaces are simply that it can contain 0 to multiple spaces.  I realize this doesn't sanitize a maze since you could create a row of all walls but this is what is asked for and the solver for the maze is responsible for giving that feedback when something like that happens.

Comment: Excuse the large number of edits.  I thought I could just wing it.  I finally got out Regexr and worked on it and tested it -- hopefully thoroughly enough. :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the tip Regexr is actually very helpful I never heard of it.  Sorry this is my first semester of java.